# What does the #feedback selector reference in the JQueryUI demos

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm looking specifically at the "Selectable" demos. Here is the example code for reference:

```
<style>
  #feedback { font-size: 1.4em; }
  #selectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
  #selectable .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
  #selectable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
  #selectable li { margin: 3px; padding: 0.4em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<ol id="selectable">
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 7</li>
</ol>


</body>
</html>
```

None of the HTML contains an id of "feedback" and I've tried commenting the `#feedback` styling in and out, but I can't see a difference.

Thanks

Comment: link to the jquery ui docs in question?

Comment: I think is a copy paste it is needed only in the third demo http://jqueryui.com/selectable/#serialize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think is copy-paste of the example css code of the jQuery UI selectable. It is needed only for the third example [`Serialize`](http://jqueryui.com/selectable/#serialize) look at the `<p id="feedback">`.

Demo code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Selectable - Serialize</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />

  <style>
  #feedback { font-size: 1.4em; }
  #selectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
  #selectable .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
  #selectable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
  #selectable li { margin: 3px; padding: 0.4em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable({
      stop: function() {
        var result = $( "#select-result" ).empty();
        $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function() {
          var index = $( "#selectable li" ).index( this );
          result.append( " #" + ( index + 1 ) );
        });
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p id="feedback">
<span>You've selected:</span> <span id="select-result">none</span>.
</p>

<ol id="selectable">
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 6</li>
</ol>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's only used in the third demo...

In the serialize demo, if you check devtools, you'll see:

```
<p id="feedback">
<span>You've selected:</span> <span id="select-result">none</span>.
</p>
```